# Docker pull Django image and run container

Tags: django, docker

So, I have followed [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) tutorial by Docker to create a Django image.

It completely works on my local machine by just running a `docker-compose up` command from the root directory of my project.

But, after pushing the image to docker hub https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/vivanks/firsttry

I am pulling the image to another machine and then running:

```
docker run -p 8020:8020 vivanks/firsttry
```

But it's not getting started and showing this error:

> EXITED(0)

Can anyone help me on how to pull this image and run it?

My Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
  version: '3'
    
  services:
    db:
      image: postgres
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    web:
      build: .
      command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
      volumes:
        - .:/code
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      depends_on:
        - db
```

Comment: please edit your question and add the final version of your Dockerfile

Comment: I have edited it @MehrdadEP your input would be really helpful

Comment: As a side note using WORKDIR /code is enough and you don't need to RUN mkdir /code
before it. note that every RUN command add an extra layer to your docker image

Comment: Yeah thanks for it.
Though currently, it's not running on another machine completely @MehrdadEP
You can try an pull the image from `docker push vivanks/firsttry:latest`

Comment: From your docker compose I'm guessing you don't create the needed database in your db container. Is that correct?

Comment: I have created the Database. Using `docker-compose up` it was running perfectly fine on my machine with proper database. `docker-compose up` only create the database 
image automatically.

Comment: I have followed this tutorial https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/ in case you want to replicate the issue.

Comment: If it helps in running the container on different pc then ok

Comment: @MehrdadEP, in the compose file, the current directory is mounted in the directory where the source and requirements.txt are copied at build-time...apart from not having a proper database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @larsks mentioned in his answer your problem is that your command is in the Compose file, rather than in Dockerfile.

To run your project on another machine as-is, use the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3' 
services:
    db:
      image: postgres
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    web:
      image: vivanks/firsttry:latest
      command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      depends_on:
        - db
```

If you already added `CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` to your Dockerfile and rebuilt the image, the above can be further simplified to:

```
version: '3' 
services:
    db:
      image: postgres
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    web:
      image: vivanks/firsttry:latest
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      depends_on:
        - db
```

Using `docker run` will fail in either case, since it won't set up a database.

Edit:

OP, I admire your persistence, but at the same time do not understand the insistence on using Docker CLI rather than docker-compose. I recommend using one of the above `docker-compose.yml` files to start your app.

Nevertheless, I accept the challenge of running it without docker-compose.

Your application fails to start when you use `docker run` command, because it tries to connect to database on host `db`, which does not exist. In your (and mine) `docker-compose.yml` there is a definition of a service called *db*. Docker-compose uses that definition to set up a database container for you and makes it available for your application under hostname `db`.

To start your application without using docker-compose, you need to manually do everything it does for you automatically (the commands below assume you have added `CMD...` to your `Dockerfile`:

```
docker network create --driver bridge django-test-network
docker run --detach --env POSTGRES_DB=postgres --env POSTGRES_USER=postgres --env POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres --network django-test-network --name db postgres:latest
docker run -it --rm --network django-test-network --publish 8080:8000 vivanks/firsttry:latest
```

The above 3 commands create a new bridged network, create and start a detached (background) container with properly configured database connected to that network and finally create and start an attached (foreground) container based on your image, also attached to that new network. Since both containers are on the same, **non-default** bridged network, your application will be able to resolve hostname `db` to internal IP address of the database container and start properly.

Once you shut it down with `Ctrl+C`, the container with your application will delete itself (as it was started with option `--rm`), but you need to also manually clean up the rest. To do so run the following commands:

```
docker stop db
docker rm -v db
docker network remove django-test-network
```

The first one stops the database container, the second one removes it and its anonymous volume and the third one removes the network.

I hope this explains everything.

Comment: How to make what work? I already told you how to run your project on another machine.

Comment: conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known


I am getting this error with the above-mentioned changes on running `docker run vivanks/firsttry`

Comment: Any help here @Konrad Botor

Answer (score 1):

Your `Dockerfile` doesn't specify a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`. When you run...

```
docker run -p 8020:8020 vivanks/firsttry
```

...the container has nothing to do (which means it will actually try to start a Python interactive shell, but since you're not allocating a terminal with `-t`, the shell just exits. Successfully). In your `docker-compose.yml`, you're passing in an explicit command:

```
      command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

So the equivalent `docker run` command line would look like:

```
docker run -docker run -p 8020:8020 vivanks/firsttry python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

But you probably want to bake that into your `Dockerfile` like this:

```
CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: Ok so after adding the CMD
How can I run that image?

Comment: With this I am getting an error:     ```conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known```

Comment: Any help here? @larsks